# Change x-values in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting a column of data which represents a time series in gnuplot. Every value represents a time value after 500 iterations / time units. Can I tell gnuplot to multiply the x-values it displays by 500?

I thought this would be a standard problem since every time one has to plot a time series one needs to tell the plotting program what time unit each iteration has.

I don't want to create an extra column with x-values manually, since I have a lot of different data of different length. I don't want to create a x column for everyone of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have only a single column, gnuplot uses the row number as x value. This can be accessed by the pseudo column `0` and scaled like

```
plot 'datafile' using ($0*500):1
```

or equivalently, if you're calling this from a shell script

```
plot 'datafile' using (column(0)*500):1
```

Comment: As I said, I unfortunately don't have a x column. I have only a y-column representing the y-values in a time series. The temporal spacing between every y-value is the same.

Comment: Still no luck. I'm using a plotting script (bash-script) which is why `$0` is interpreted as the first command line argument.

Comment: How should I know? You haven't mentioned this with a single word... Then use `column(0)*500`.

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't think of that in the beginning. It works now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Or \$0 instead of column(0)

Comment: @JonatanÖström in this case probably yes, but it can happen that you must also escape the backslash, once or twice... `column` always works